# How to assign file path from QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames to a variable could be called outside the class?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to pyqt, and currently trying to get the file dialog function to work. It is able to print the file names inside the class and function, but not able to get the file name saved to a variable outside the function.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class open_file(QWidget):

    global file_name

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Select Image'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.openFileNamesDialog()
        self.show()

    def openFileNamesDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "",
                                                "Images (*.png *.jpg)", options=options)
        return files



names = ex.openFileNamesDialog()
print(names)
```

I expect the file names to be printed after selecting files, but nothing gets printed

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets  import (QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog,
                         QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class OpenFile(QWidget):
#    global file_name

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Select Image'
        self.left   = 100
        self.top    = 100
        self.width  = 640
        self.height = 480

        self.initUI()

        self.label  = QLabel()
        button = QPushButton("Click me", clicked=self.openFileNamesDialog)


        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        vbox.addWidget(button)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
#        self.openFileNamesDialog()

    def openFileNamesDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "",
                                                "Images (*.png *.jpg)", options=options)
#        return files
        if  files:
            print(*files, sep="\n")
            self.label.setText(", \n".join(files))

#names = ex.openFileNamesDialog() print(names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = OpenFile()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]